# Python expected an intended block error if/else

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, eclipse

Hello im getting in this script an indentationError

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("mainMenuRoutes").click()
time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(2)
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="m-btn full-btn pos-btn" and @id="departAll"]').is_displayed():
    print("Routen werden gestartet")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="m-btn full-btn pos-btn" and @id="departAll"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id("mainMenuRoutes").click
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print("Es konnte nichts gestartet werden")

if kerosin_kaufen:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainMenuFuel").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    KerosinCheckA = driver.find_element_by_id("pricePerLbsOut").text
    KerosinCheck = re.sub("\,","",KerosinCheckA)
    print (KerosinCheck)
    if KerosinCheck >= kerosin_max:
        print("Kerosin ist billig - wird gekauft!")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#iAmount").send_keys(kerosin_billig)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fuelBtnPurchase").click()
    else:
        BestandA = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#holdingOut").text
        Bestand = re.sub("\,","",BestandA)
        print(Bestand)
        if Bestand <= kerosin_min:
            print("zu wenig Kerosin - wird gekauft")
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#iAmount").send_keys(kerosin_leer)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fuelBtnPurchase").click()
            print("Gekauft!")
        else:           
else:
    print ("h")
```

at the last else I'm getting this error:
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

I dont know what to do when i write an elif in between of those im getting this error in the elif.
Hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have "else" twice near the end of the code snippet.

On some other things that I would change:

1. You call time.sleep() twice at the start of the code, one right just after the other
2. Remove time.sleep() altogether and wait until a certain element is shown instead. You can either set implicit wait globally, which will affect all of the webdriver`s locator functions, or create a function with an explicit wait that will end when a certain element is available in the DOM. More about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618695/when-to-use-implicit-wait-and-where-to-use
3. You seem to mix locators a lot. It`s a good practice to use only one type of locator (id, xpath,...). Makes the code easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks I made a time.sleep at the else: after print("Gekauft!") 
now its working

Comment: @LaurenzZ dont hesitate to mark answers as correct once you issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Python expects a statement after an `else` statement. The error is caused by the empty `else` just after `print("Gekauft!")`. The error message is a bit confusing though. When you remove this `else` the error will be resolved.

Imagine you have the following invalid code:

```
print("Check if water is boiling")
if temperature >= 100:
    print("Boiling")
else:
print("Not boiling") # Oops, forgot to indent this line.
print("Check finished")
```

While you meant to code this:

```
print("Check if water is boiling")
if temperature >= 100:
    print("Boiling")
else:
    print("Not boiling")
print("Check finished")
```

Then this makes clear why the compiler complains about expecting an indented block of code.